# Ethereum old private messages site

Tags: blockchain, whisper, message, p2p

I know this may be a long shot but I am looking for an old (was functional 1 - 2 years ago) messaging site on the ethereum network.

**Sob story begins**

I wrote my now ex a love message on this website through an eth message, and I remember I was able to test it with her wallet and see the message by just inputting her eth address, so no signin required to check the mailbox, it just showed the result.

**Sob story ends**

I have done a lot of checking but I cannot find anywhere this service, didnt bookmark it and all current sites require either the download of an app or something similar.

I tried the common ones you find on google, like https://ethmail.cc/

I also tried checking for all my transaction messages but it seems this app did not direct the messages directly to the destination address, so I cannot filter by "Sent to:"

The interface of the site was a bit retro, with just some space to input the address and some more space to see the messages.

Hopefully someone has seen or used this service in the past? this was around 1-2 years ago.